# jQuery Live + mouseup function, get only the child element active

Tags: jquery, live, mouseup

HTML

```
<div class="mybox" id="element1">
    <div class="mybox" id="element2">
        <div class="mybox" id="element3">
        </div>
        <div class="mybox" id="element4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".mybox").live("mouseup", function(event) {
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Okay, so my question is how to get only the active div (the one that I have clicked on, not all the parents). When I click on element2 I get element2 & then "element1" active, when I click on element3 I get element2 & then element1 active again, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick suggestion: `live` has been deprecated for `.on`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see all those alerts is due to event bubbling. Each time you click on an element, the event is propagated up the chain. Every element which has a click event attached along the way will be executed.

To ensure you only execute the code when the current element has been clicked on and to ignore bubbled events change your event to check if that the current element is the one you clicked on using [**event.target**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and only then execute your intended code:

```
$(".mybox").live("mouseup", function(event) {
    if(event.target === this){
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AcJT7/) - using live

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later `live()` was deprecated and [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on)  is now the preferred way of attaching and removing events.

To use `on()` instead you can do this:

```
(document).on("mouseup", ".mybox", function(event) {
    if (event.target === this) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7EhuV/) - using on()

When using `on()` you specify the closest static element which in the example above is the document. However, if you have a closer static element you should be using that instead of `document`.

I have linked all the required documentation in the answer but to summarise again.

#### Resources

- [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live) - has all the details on why it has been deprecated
- [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on) - preferred since 1.7
- [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) - which can be used instead of live since 1.4.2 or later

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Yes, I'm using on(), just typed live() in here cause I'm still used to to the older version.

Comment: I have function that traces the box height, and after I re-size the box once let say to 255px, it somehow remembers it, if I try to re-size over 255px, the "event.target === this" returns false all on the same box. If the box i re-sized between initial value and 255px "event.target === this" returns true. (I'm using jQuery UI), have added "click mouseup mousemove" as an additional events.

Comment: @KrasenT: Would you be able to create a fiddle, replicating the issue you are having?

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure it out, just needed to separate the resize and move actions into two different function.

Answer (score 0):

As Francois wrote the effect is called "event bubbling". But jquery has it's own function to prevent the event to go up the chain: [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("p").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

Only if this fails to work for your special case, you should use the solution of comparing event targets.

Comment: while `stopPropagation` will work it is a lot to maintain if you have a possible `n-th` number of elements to prevent bubbling up from. You also end up with a lot of attached events purely for the sake of preventing propogation but with no other function intend. But yes, this should work as well.

Comment: The 'problem' on comparing events is, that your function might be called a lot of times untill the end of the chain. My understanding of stopPropagation is that it quits the event chain - and js does not have to do more work than necessary. As live is deprecated the conflict of stopPropagation and live should be addressed by changing live to on.